# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 118

Tags: java, swing, java-8

I have upgraded from jdk1.6(32) to jdk1.8(64) and Netbeans from 6.* to 8.*.
Configured setup and successfully updated the project.jar files. Few of the external jars are taken as it is which are listed below:

```
file.reference.bcmail-jdk16-136.jar 
file.reference.bcprov-jdk16-136.jar
file.reference.jcommon-1.0.10.jar
file.reference.jdepend.jar
file.reference.jfreechart-1.0.9.jar
file.reference.log4j-1.2.14.jar
file.reference.registry.jar
file.reference.swingx.jar
file.reference.jshrink.jar
```

Now, I am prepared app.exe from inno setup and deployed exe, I am getting following error pop-up message when I am try to run exe: "A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again"

When try to run from command prompt I got following stacktrace:
  C:\Users\100755224>java -jar C:\Dev_TSOFT\Sources\installer\tsoft\TSOFT.jar

===============================

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap     frame at branch target 118
 Exception Details:
 Location:
 com/alstom/tsoft/Main.<init>([Ljava/lang/String;)V @56: ifeq
 Reason:
 Expected stackmap frame at this location.
 Bytecode:
 0x0000000: 2ab7 0002 2a11 7d91 b500 032a 1204 b500
 0x0000010: 052a bb00 0659 2ab7 0007 b500 082a bb00
 0x0000020: 0959 117d 9112 042a b400 08b7 000b b500
 0x0000030: 0c2a b400 0cb6 000d 9900 3eb8 000e b800
 0x0000040: 0fa7 0004 4d04 b800 112b be04 a000 142a
 0x0000050: bb00 1259 2b03 32b7 0013 b500 01a7 000e
 0x0000060: 2abb 0012 59b7 0014 b500 012a b400 01b6
 0x0000070: 0015 04b6 0016 b1
 Exception Handler Table:
 bci [59, 65] => handler: 68

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I have set the library and source JDK version to jdk8. Please suggest, its a work stopper for me since 4 days.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say (64), do you mean 64-bit or u64? What is the exact version of the JVM?

Comment: C:\>java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: Does inno setup do bytecode transformations or do you use any other bytecode processing tool?

Comment: sorry, I am not sure.

Comment: It’s crucial that any bytecode processing tool must be capable of handling stackmap attributes correctly. In Java 6, there was a fallback to the old verifier for incorrect code, which doesn’t exist for Java 8 code. You have to check which tools or libraries may be responsible and update them. If in doubt, update every software of your tool chain that is older than ten years…

Answer (score 0):

I came to know where the problem is,

inno setup is using old jre i.e 1.6, I need to update that jre.
Now the question is how to update inno setup jre files ?

Please let me know if any one is aware.

Thanks